# Bloques Anónimos PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola soy nuevo con ORACLE y quiero saber si es posible declarar 2 variables en un bloque anónimo las cuales pueda modificar cada vez que ejecute el script y que dicho bloque anónimo me devuelva el resultado de la consulta, cabe mencionar que busco una opción que no sea un procedimiento almacenado.

```
DECLARE
FECHAINI DATE := '01-ENE-2020';
FECHAFIN DATE := '31-MAR-2020';
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM VENTAS WHERE FECHAV BETWEEN FECHAINI AND FECHAFIN;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Un bloque anónimo de Oracle PL/SQL puede usar todo lo que el lenguaje PL/SQL ofrece y ser todo lo complejo que desee.

Incluso puede tener funciones, procedimientos y anidamiento de funciones y procedimientos.

```
DECLARE
 procedure print(isbTexto  varchar2)
 is
 begin
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line(isbTexto);
 End print;
 --
 Function fdtFecha(iTexto varchar2)
 return date
 is
 Begin
   return(to_date(iTexto,'dd-mon-yyyy'));
 End fdtFecha;
 --
 procedure pBuscar(idtInicio  varchar2,
                   idtFinal   varchar2
                  )
 is
   cursor cuVentas
   is
   SELECT * 
   FROM VENTAS 
   WHERE FECHAV BETWEEN fdtFecha(idtInicio)
                    AND fdtFecha(idtFinal);
 Begin
   for rcVentas in cuVentas loop
       /* suponga que existe una columna de nombre "venta_id" */
       print(rcVentas.venta_id);
   End loop;
 End pBuscar
Begin
  Print('Inicio');
  --
  pBuscar('01-ENE-2020',
          '31-MAR-2020'
          );
  print('Final);
END;
```